# How to create a report showing a subset of contacts and their tags

Tags: custom-reports

I need help creating a custom report, please. I have approximately 15 tags (health, advice, benefits, etc), and I need to know how to create a report showing which of the contacts in my database are associated with them. I can run a report that creates the appropriate list of contacts, but it doesn't show which tags each contact has. I hope this makes sense!

Many thanks,

cdwmrcf

Comment: Hi @cdwmrcf, what CMS and what version of Civi are you using?

Comment: Hi Allen, my Civi version is 4.1.5. I don't know where to look for the CMS version? Many thanks, Chris Williams

Comment: By CMS he meant Drupal, Joomla or WordPress. or given how old your install is, possibly standalone. When you log in to your site, what url do you go to? Just the bit after your domain name.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below step get the contacts report with tag values.

1. Find contact using search option. (sitename/civicrm/contact/search?reset=1)
2. Click on search without apply any filter if you want report for all contact.
3. Select the contacts and then perform the action **export contacts**
4. select this option **Select fields for export and Do not merge** on this page.
5. Now on this page you select the fields that you want in your report.

That's all.

Comment: @cdwmrcf Good to know that it helped  you. Please accept the answer it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the Tags on the screen, go to Search Builder, and enter something like: Contacts > Tags > Not empty.

This should give you a table with Name and Tags, and you can then export too if you want.

NOTE: any suggestion offered may not be available on an old system like 4.1.x. Also note that if your system is publicly accessible it is unlikely to be 'secure' since many security releases have come out since that version.